# Python: Mechanize error only shows when running code from text editor but works fine when running directly from idle shell

Tags: python, shell, import, mechanize, attributeerror

When I type the code

```
            import mechanize
            import webbrowser

            br = mechanize.Browser()
```

direct into the shell the code runs fine. However if I run from text editor this error comes up:

> br = mechanize.Browser() 
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Browser'

Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you called your `.py` file as `mechanize.py.`

Change it to another name. Python trying to import your file as `mechanize`.